# Typescript in cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, typescript

I created a new JS object in the cshtml file. I want to use TS interface validation on this object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clusteredPins = [];
@foreach (var d in Model)
{
    @:clusteredPins.push({latitude: @d.location.latitude});
}
```

I defined IClasteredPin interface in a interface.ts file but I don't see any way to use typescript in the cshtml file. My ideal code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clusteredPins:IClasteredPin = [];
@foreach (var d in Model)
{
    @:clusteredPins.push({latitude: @d.location.latitude});
}
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695451/using-typescript-in-cshtml-files) but the answers are not what I am looking. I am not sure people who answered that question understands the problem. I don't want to run TS on client site. I want to use ts in cshtml like it was in a ts file.